# Record audio without simultaneous playback html5

Tags: javascript, html, audio, record

I've looked at many demos and every one of them when recording audio, plays back what you are saying at the same time. The issue with this is when recording without an external mic it causes the laptop's speakers and mic to interfere and spit out loud-ear piercing white noise.

Is there a way to record audio using html5 and javascript without having it playback while you record?

Comment: Trying to find an answer myself, right now I just mute the speakers then do my recording. But when I try to listen to the playback it still gives me the feedback because the audio is enabled.